# compute average surface temperature from nc4 file with each lat long

Tags: python, shapefile, polygon, netcdf

I have nc4 file and I have one shapefile. So I want to read temperature for each latitude and longitude. I used that code-

```
import numpy as np
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import geopandas as gpd
import shapefile
data = Dataset("file.nc4","r")
//result -dimensions(sizes): lon(1440), lat(600), time(1), bnds(2)
          //variables(dimensions): float32 lat(lat), float32 lon(lon),float64 time(time), float64 time_bnds(time,bnds), float32 AvgSurfT_inst(time,lat,lon)

sf = shapefile.Reader('DISTRCT_BDY.shp')
for row in sf.shapeRecords():
    #print (row.shape.points)
    print (row.record)
    //result - ['AHMADNAGAR', 'MAHARASHTRA', 1355040.74938, 16554473772.2]

for temp in data.variables['AvgSurfT_inst'][:] :
        for tmp in temp:
            print (tmp)
```

so I am confused how to use lat and long in nc4 file to compute temperature.